# PRINTER HP 3070A HPLIP VERSION NOT SUPPORTED

Tags: printer

The HPLIP installed version not supported my HP printer 3070a but Linux Mint, Deepin and other OS support my printer. How do i make it work?

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-3070a-e-all-in-one-printer-series-b611/4311847/model/4311848

Answer (score 1):

If it's supported in Ubuntu 16.04, it's also supported on eOS Loki. I had a similar problem with a HP printer. When you first plug it in, you have to select it from a list. The names are approximate. I have a Deskjet Ink Advantage 3785. When I selected from the Ink Advantage series it didn't work, I had to select it from the Deskjet 3700 series. So try reinstalling it with a different series.